# Can I remove Assignable attribute from an id field in ObjectBox

Tags: android, objectbox

The question is about ObjectBox db version 2.2.0

Can I remove `assignable = true` attribute from the field that is already in prod in case if we haven't put any custom numbers there and basically they are auto-assignable? Will it migrate correctly? What are the risks?

```
@Id(assignable = true)
private long id;
```

to

```
@Id
private long id;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that should work. But please do your own testing too. :)